# Binary Search with strings in C

Tags: c, string, search, binary, char

I have implemented this binary search algorithm with the goal of finding a desired char contained in an array. I've tried doing the 'if' 'else' comparisons the standard way, considering the ASCII table: [ if ( searchElement > arrayChar[mid] ... etc ]. That didn't seem to work, so I realized that maybe it had something to do with string comparisons. I'm now using the function strcmp and using its returned value to compare:

(If string1 < string2 -> negative value. If string1 > string2 -> positive value. If string1 == string2 -> 0. )

which it doesn't seem to be working as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int binarySearch(int arraySize, char arrayChar[]) {
    
    // Variable declaration;
    char searchElement[2];
    int startingPoint = 0, endingPoint = arraySize - 1;
    
    // Input for desired search element;
    printf("\nSearch for: ");
    scanf(" %c", &searchElement);
    
    while (startingPoint <= endingPoint) {
        int mid = (startingPoint + endingPoint) / 2;
        if (strcmp(searchElement, arrayChar[mid]) == 0) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (strcmp(searchElement, arrayChar[mid]) < 0)
            endingPoint = mid - 1;
        else {
            if (strcmp(searchElement, arrayChar[mid]) > 0)
                startingPoint = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main() {
        
    // Array declaration;
    char randomCharArray[7] = {'a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
    
    
    // Calling  binarySearch() ;
    if (binarySearch(6, randomCharArray) == -1) printf("Element not found!");
    else printf("Element found in [%d] .", binarySearch(6, randomCharArray));

    return 1;
    
}
```

Comment: Reading with `%c` does not ensure that `searchElement[1] == '\0'`.  And string comparisons depend on null-terminated strings.  But since you're pass `arrayChar[mid]` to `strcmp()`, you're passing a character, not a string.  In fact, you should replace the calls to `strcmp()` with `if (searchElement == arrayChar[mid])`, etc because you are comparing single characters, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having trouble with the distinction between individual `char` values and strings, which are contiguous sequences of `char` values ending with one having value 0.  Pairs of individual `char` values can be compared with the standard relational and equality-test operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, *etc*.).  Pairs of strings can be compared via the `strcmp()` function.  **Individual `char`s cannot be directly compared with strings**, and you don't have strings anyway because neither the contents of `binarySearch()`'s `searchElement` nor the contents of `main()`'s `randomCharArray` are null-terminated.

That leads me to suggestion 1: make `searchElement` a `char`, not an array, since you know you need it to represent a single `char` only:

```
char searchElement;
```

Having done that, you can now (suggestion 2) compare the value of `searchElement` to elements of `arrayChar` via the standard operators, as you say originally tried to do.  For example,

```
    // with 'searchElement' as a char, not a char[]:
    if (searchElement == arrayChar[mid]) {
```

Alternatively, if you kept `searchElement` as an array then you could use `searchElement[0]` to access its first `char` for comparison.